# google appengine does not print array value

Tags: python, arrays, google-app-engine, random

I was starting with the google app engine and was trying some quick learning.I stumbled across this issue which does not occur on my local development environment.Here is the code

```
import random, math
random.seed()

quotesArray=[]
quotesArray.append("This is a Test1")
quotesArray.append("This is a Test2")
quotesArray.append("This is a Test3")
quotesArray.append("This is a Test4")
quotesArray.append("This is a Test5")


x = int(math.floor(random.random()*343)+1)
print quotesArray[0]+" "+str(x)
```

On my development environment the output is

```
This is a Test1 45
```

On the live site the output is

```
45
```

Can anyone please provide me some idea on why would this be so?

Comment: does this also occur when you use logging.debug() rather than print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got through a solution to this problem myself

Instead of `print` command, we have to use `sys.stdout.write('text to print')`

You need to `import sys` for the above to work.

Comment: it has probably something to do with what the standard output is...Might be a bug in the app engine which cannot recognize where the output of `print` needs to go...

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the behavior is different between the dev server and production, but in a web application, if you simply `print` stuff to stdout without first sending HTTP headers, you should expect that your output is going to get mangled.  You should at a minimum be printing "\r\n" before any other output, although not using some sort of wsgi framework is a recipe for frustration anyway.

Comment: I did put in the following code and still no output..its a blank screen on the live environment, but localhost prints nicely `    print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
loveQuotes=[]
loveQuotes.append("Test1")
loveQuotes.append("Test2")
loveQuotes.append("Test3")
loveQuotes.append("Test4")

print loveQuotes[1]`